# Show a form without taking focus

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a form that will be on top of all the windows and also when it shows it self it won't take focus from other windows.

I did that the form will be ontop of the windows:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

But I can't figure out how to prevent the form from taking focus while displayed.

Comment: @Nemanja Boric It's still taking focus..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking about wfp, try setting the property `ShowActivated="False"`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Focus()` or your parent form.

```
//create a spawn a child form
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show();

//give your parent form the focus
this.Focus();
```

This will keep your Form1 on top when the second spawns.

Comment: I want to prevent Form from gaining any focus..